# remove locked by android device manager message

Tags: android-device-manager

I have played with Android device manager and I have blocked my phone. I have deblocked but everytime my phone enters into standyby it apears me the message "locked by android device manager" and I have to enter the password again.

Do you know how to remove this message?

Answer (score 2):

Remove "locked by android device manager" without factory reset.

Here are the steps:

1. Ask the owner in order to get the passcode or password
2. (Once you have the passcode or password) Go to settings > Lock screen
3. Enter passcode or password
4. Select none or whatever you choose to use
5. In order to see it, swipe down from the area at the top (Notification panel)
6. You will see a new (android device manager icon) at the top of your screen. The icon looks like a raindrop (green in color) with a bullseye (white in color) icon inside the circle
7. Tap and hold the ADM (Android Device Manager) icon
8. Tap app info
9. Tap Manage Space
10. Tap clear all data

Now the icon has been removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the password from Settings -> Security -> Screen lock, enter the specified password and choose your desired new lock type. If you previously didn't have a PIN, Pattern or Password lock, use the Slide option.

Comment: I've done that but it keept apearing me the same message. I had to restore all the settings to make it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had to perform a factory reset, because I think I've tried everything. Changed the password on android device manager and blocked again. It appeared the new password, I have deblocked again, went to Settings -> Security -> Screen lock entered the new password and I choose None. I restarted the phone but it keept appearing me the text "locked by android device manager". After the phone ringed on phone that I set on androide device manager I could enter the phone without entering the pasword.

So I performed a factory reset and erased everything from the phone and got rid of all the problems.

I use an zte blade q maxi phone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings >display >security >credential storage> clear credential..
It will do it for you :)

Comment: Not sure how that should be related. The settings you refer to are security certificates for SSL you've added yourself (e.g. for websites using self-signed certificates). Even if there were any related certificates, that would just affect the ability to access a site/server, but certainly not a device-manager lock. Can you give a reference?

Answer (score 0):

The key to unlocking and removing this is hard for the galaxy note 3. I had to reset the password multiple times because with the note 3 if you put a passcode it wont let you,but if you put a password it will always be wrong...So the only solution is putting in the orignal password instead of the device manager.

I tried to put a new password on my phone because my mom changed my password and wouldn't tell me because I got a C+ on my report card. She acts like she pays the bill for it.

The ultimate thing to do is not to put a password on it from device manager!

Answer (score 0):

Get into the phone change the password to a pin like 1234. Go back to find my phone and set the lock phone on the find my phone to the same pin you already have your phone set to. Used LGL21G

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's how I fixed mine on Moto X.

Go to Settings>Security>ScreenLock>ClearCredentials

Go back to Screen lock, the option to choose "None" as the screen lock is now available.

Thanks for the help Sumit Sharma :)